# Css transition is not linear

Tags: css, html, transition

I’m trying to achieve some nice transition effects when hovering after a image.(a hover div to appear from the same direction as the mouse ).

Everything works fine except that the “hover in”  transition is not in straight line but more like in a diagonal & fill kind of way.(in the example below the transition is from left: -378px; to left : 0px / top is 0).

Normal state:

```
<div class="hover_effect initial_hover slideFromLeft" style="display: block;">link aici</div>
```

Hover state (classes are removed and added via jQuery):

```
<div class="slideFromLeft hover_effect initial_hover slideLeft" style="display: block;">link aici</div>
```

I want the movement to be in a straight line  like the hover out transition which works fine. Can you point me the bug ?

This is the html & css code:

```
<div class="portfolio-sample regular-portfolio coding-2   isotope-item" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);">
<img width="455" height="295" src="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/env0251-455x295.jpg" class="attachment-portfolio-two wp-post-image" alt="env025">        
<div class="slideFromLeft hover_effect initial_hover slideLeft" style="display: block;">link aici</div>
<div class="custom_slider_shadow"></div>
</div>
```

Thank you!

```
 .hover_effect{
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.initial_hover{
position: absolute;
background: rgba(75,75,75,0.7);
width: 378px;
height: 245px;
top: 260px;
}

.slideFromLeft {
top: 0px; 
left: -378px;
}

.slideLeft {
left: 0px;
}
```

Answer :
OK i figure it out - it was because the initial_hover class was added after the slideFromLeft  on hover. Once i reverse these it works as i expected

Answer (score 2):

It is not linear because it is specified to be not linear. If you want a linear transition, you should change both `ease-in-out` and `ease` to `linear` in the styling for `.hover_effect`.

Comment: MY mistake on initial question , I want the movement to be in straight line not "linear" like i originaly posted.